# SQL query gives no results when one of the tables is empty

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to perform a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT
    t1.*
FROM
    `table1` t1,
    `table2` t2
WHERE
    t1.x = 1
```

and the table called table2 (t2) is empty but inside t1 there are entries.

For example this query works perfect:

```
SELECT
    t1.*
FROM
    `table1` t1
WHERE
    t1.x = 1
```

So just by adding the second table t2 in the FROM part the query gives no results anymore. So I don't understand what is going on here. In my case it should be possible that one of the tables is empty but the query still needs to give results. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is it ACTUALLY `WHERE
    t1.x = 1` or is more like `WHERE t1.x = t2.y`?

Comment: If you use the relevant JOIN syntax you can solve this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is using an implied `JOIN` between `table1` and `table2`, and could be rewritten as:

```
SELECT  t1.*
  FROM  `table1` t1,
    CROSS JOIN `table2` t2
  WHERE t1.x = 1
```

This is `JOIN`ing everything in `table1` against everything in `table2`.  However, as `table2` is empty *there is nothing to join to*.

With an implied `CROSS JOIN`, results are *only* returned when the row on both sides of the join is matched, which in this case it cannot be.  Therefore, nothing is returned.

If you rewrote the statement to use a `LEFT JOIN`, you would see all results from `table1`, *and only matching results* from `table2`:

```
SELECT  t1.*
  FROM  `table1` t1,
    LEFT JOIN `table2` t2 ON 1 = 1
  WHERE t1.x = 1
```

Incidentally, typically you would only use this kind of query if there is a relationship in the data between `table1` and `table2`.  In this case, you would `JOIN` on the related columns, like so:

```
SELECT  t1.*
  FROM  `table1` t1,
    LEFT JOIN `table2` t2 ON t2.matchedColumn = t1.matchedColumn
  WHERE t1.x = 1
```